# how to repeat only $par in optim function and for loop for R stat

Tags: r

i want only $par repeated for 5 times. i still can run my code but i have warning message as follow:

**In results[i] = m1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**

```
library(evd)
results=0
for(i in 1:5)
{
trendgev=function(v,z)
{
beta0=v[1]
beta1=v[2]
mu=v[1]+v[2]*t
sig=v[3]
xi=v[4]
if (min(1+xi*(z-mu)/sig) <=0) return (10^10)
if (sig<0) return(10^10)

a=(1+xi*(z-mu))/sig
b=(-1/xi)

f=(1/sig)*(a^(b-1))*exp(-a^b)

ff=log(f)
ans=-sum(ff)  
return(ans)
}

t=c(1:1000)
beta0=1
beta1=0.4

z=rgev(50,0,1,1)
zz=z+beta1*t

starts=c(0.1, -0.9,1.1,0.5)

m1=optim(par=starts, fn=trendgev, z=zz) ; m1

results[i]=m1

print(results[i])
}
print(m1)
```

the output from my coding is as follow. please help me in order to discard the warning message and i can repeat 5 times only on 'par' value
    [[1]]
    [1] -0.2053160  0.4000491  2.3253354  1.3603900

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.07303119 0.39996344 1.11404626 0.93861174

[[1]]
[1] -0.01384496  0.39998626  1.14267411  1.05170904

[[1]]
[1] -1.0078745  0.4004017  1.0993075  4.3916078

[[1]]
[1] 0.06992641 0.39997072 1.05224910 1.09107480

Warning messages:
1: In results[i] = m1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In results[i] = m1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In results[i] = m1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In results[i] = m1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In results[i] = m1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> print(m1)
$par
[1] 0.06992641 0.39997072 1.05224910 1.09107480

$value
[1] 2080.907

$counts
function gradient 
     501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

can i get the output as follow(only repeat and mention the 'par' value)?

```
[[1]]
[1] -0.2053160  0.4000491  2.3253354  1.3603900

[[1]]
[1] 0.07303119 0.39996344 1.11404626 0.93861174

[[1]]
[1] -0.01384496  0.39998626  1.14267411  1.05170904

[[1]]
[1] -1.0078745  0.4004017  1.0993075  4.3916078

[[1]]
[1] 0.06992641 0.39997072 1.05224910 1.09107480
```

Comment: Please provide the result that you want in this example. Something like **desired result:  X Y...**

Comment: Also, the code in the question gives is incomplete.  After pasting it into R one is left with a + asking for more input.  Please fix.

Comment: does it mean that my coding are incorrect?but why do i still have the output?